# What is maximum fuse in Minecraft?(TNT Fuse)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know what is maximum TNT fuse in Minecraft. Because I want to make Primed TNT with maximum fuse in my Minecraft map.

Comment: Have you done any prior research before asking? The answer appears as Google's "instant answer" when searching "minecraft maximum tnt fuse" on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum TNT fuse is the largest number that can be stored in a NBT `TAG_Short`, which is 32767 ticks. There are 20 ticks in a second, which means that 32767 ticks approximates to `00h:27m:18.35s`.

Summoning a TNT with a maximum fuse is as simple as including the NBT for a `/summon` command:

```
/summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:32767s}
```

The `s` is a data type, meaning that the number is a `TAG_Short`. It is a good practice to include your data types in the NBT, so that it's not ambiguous over which number type you want.